# How to filter word temp file

Tags: c#, filter, ms-word, temporary-files

Right now, I'm developing a winform system.I want to filter word temp file or temp filename.When someone open a word file ,in my system he will see the temp file .

And then doing some operation with temp file, the system will throw an Exception .

I just want filter the file and don't throw the Exception .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Alex\Desktop").GetFiles()
    .Where(arg => !arg.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden) || arg.Extension != ".docx")
    .ToList();
```

You can also add limiting by file name prefix:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Alex\Desktop").GetFiles()
    .Where(arg => !(arg.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden) && arg.Extension == ".docx" && arg.Name.StartsWith("~$")))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Justin - this is lambda expression. Try it.

Comment: Ok! I got it. It's amazing and awsome! Thank you! +1